# SQL Server 2008: UPDATE COLUMNS based on priorities

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a scenario where I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (payee_ID int, NetAmount decimal(9,2))
INSERT INTO #tableA (Payee_ID,NetAmount)
VALUES (2408332,1539.18)


CREATE TABLE #TableB (Payee_ID int,Priority int,formatTag char(1), Rate decimal(5,2), Netamount decimal(9,2), dedicatedAmt decimal(9,2))

INSERT INTO #TableB (Payee_ID, Priority, FormatTag, Rate)

VALUES
(2408332,   1,  ‘F’,    500.00),
(2408332,   2,  ‘P’,    0.25),
(2408332,   3,  ‘P’,    0.25),
(2408332,   4,  ‘F’,    100.00),
(2408332,   5,  ‘P’,    1.00)
```

Where FormatTag is Flat rate or percentage.

Now I want to populate the NetAmount and dedicated Amount by starting priority1 for this payee.

His `NetAmount` for priority1 will be total `net amount` from tableA. And `dedicated amount` will be the `rate` if `formattag` is `Flat rate`.

And, if `formattag` is percentage, then it will be the percentage of the total `netAmount`.

I want to go down the priorities and keep subtracting the netAmount in tableB based on the dedicatedAmmt used in the previous priority:

```
Expected result:
Payee_ID  Priority  formatTag   Rate        Netamount   dedicatedAmt
2408332   1         F           500.00      1539.18     500.00
2408332   2         P           0.25        1039.18     259.80
2408332   3         P           0.25        779.38      194.85
2408332   4         F           100.00      584.53      100.00
2408332   5         P           1.00        484.53      484.53
```

Thanks

Comment: You should tag this question with the database you are using.  I believe this is a hard problem, in the sense that you have to use recursive CTEs solve it in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using a **Recursive CTE**

In the first part of the *UNION* I am generating the *SEED* (first row) and in the other part I am generating the logic to generate the rest of the table recursively. Also, I am assuming that the priorities are incremental, you could tweak the logic here based on your actual dataset.

Something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT A.payee_id
        ,[priority]
        ,formattag
        ,rate
        ,cast(A.netamount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) netamount
        ,cast(CASE 
                WHEN formattag = 'F'
                    THEN rate
                WHEN formattag = 'p'
                    THEN rate * a.netamount
                END AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) dedicatedAmount
        ,cast(A.netamount - (
                CASE 
                    WHEN formattag = 'F'
                        THEN rate
                    WHEN formattag = 'p'
                        THEN rate * a.netamount
                    END
                ) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) ActualAmount
    FROM #Tableb B
    INNER JOIN #TableA A ON A.Payee_ID = b.Payee_ID
    WHERE priority = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.payee_id
        ,B.priority
        ,B.formattag
        ,B.rate
        ,CTE.ActualAmount
        ,cast(CASE 
                WHEN b.formattag = 'F'
                    THEN b.rate
                WHEN b.formattag = 'p'
                    THEN b.rate * CTE.ActualAmount
                END AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) dedicatedamount
        ,cast((
                CTE.ActualAmount - (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN b.formattag = 'F'
                            THEN b.rate
                        WHEN b.formattag = 'p'
                            THEN b.rate * CTE.ActualAmount
                        END
                    )
                ) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) ActualAmount
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN #TableB B ON cte.payee_id = B.payee_id
    WHERE B.priority = cte.priority + 1
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

RESULT:

```
payeeid priority    formattag   rate netamount  dedicatedAmount ActuatAmt
2408332 1   F   500.00  1539.18 500.00  1039.18
2408332 2   P   0.25    1039.18 259.80  779.39
2408332 3   P   0.25    779.39  194.85  584.54
2408332 4   F   100.00  584.54  100.00  484.54
2408332 5   P   1.00    484.54  484.54  0.00
```